# Android Client for Endpoints do not recognize Class

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

I generate a android client library for my Google Endpoint that looks like this:

```
com.appspot.<my-app-id>.auth
|_ model
|_ Auth.java
|_ AuthRequest.java
|_ AuthRequestInitializer.java
|_ AuthScopes.java
```

But when I try to import the library I get a error:

```
import com.appspot.<my-app-id>.auth.Auth; // 'Auth' red
import com.appspot.<my-app-id>.auth.model.AuthMessagesLoginResponseMessage; // 'AuthMessagesLoginResponseMessage' red
```

So I look in Auth.java file and found this error:

```
public class Check extends AuthRequest<com.appspot.<my-app-id>.auth.model.AuthMessagesCheckResponseMessage> {// 'AuthRequest' and 'AuthMesagesCheckResponseMessage' red
```

So I thought that the problem could be in AuthRequest.java and found this error:

```
 public AuthRequest(
  Auth client, String method, String uriTemplate, Object content, Class<T> responseClass) { // 'Auth' red
```

All this red only display the error message "cannot resolve symbol 'the-class-name' ".

What could be the problem?

I'm using Android Studio 0.5.1, compileSdkVersion 19, buildToolsVersion 19.0.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to use the client library generated by endpoints as described on Google Developers site (i.e.: copying the library to the "libs" folder and then right click and "Add as a Library" in the Android Studio).

But it worked when I extract the .java files from the .jar android client library to the `src > main > java` folder of my project.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the only way I can get endpoints to work is by copying the generated .java files.

Comment: What exactly did you do? The GAE SDK generated a zip file with the dependencies and a jar file with the api client. Did you extract the java files from the api jar file and paste them in the lib folder of the android project?

Comment: I use eclipse with the GAE plugin. When you generate the endpoints from within eclipse, you can then navigate to endpoint-libs/lib<your-api-name>-v1/ < your-api-name>/<your-api-name>-v1-generated-source. We actually use a script which does the same things and copies it directly into the android project.